# Availability of public transportation in Germany and Austria on December 31

Tags: trains, public-transport, germany, austria

We are travelling through Europe during December and currently we need to travel from the Munich region to Vienna on the 31st of December. Assuming we can get to Munich, would public transport be operational during this period? In some countries public transport is shut down during the festive season and we would rather move our travel dates if this is the case.

Comment: I'd like to see an example of a country where public transportation is "shut down during the festive season"

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev in Auckland, New Zealand, trains often do not run around Christmas time (usually 25th + a few days after, sometimes as long as until after New Years holidays). Buses replace these in some cases, but these too are on a reduced timetable.

Comment: @BrandonWyatt In Wellington, New Zealand, trains were replaced by buses around New Year's Day 2018/Eve 2017. And they had an extended timetable too, which seems a bit counterproductive.

Comment: London Transport does not run on the 25th of December. No underground, no busses, nada. It irks me every year.

Comment: Fear not: there will be regular service, but relatively few people will be traveling. Check out time tables at www.bahn.de and www.oebb.at.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These were the trains last year on 31st Dec ([www.bahn.de](http://www.bahn.de)).

```
München Hbf     08:17   4:13    Wien Hbf    12:30
München Hbf     09:30   4:00    Wien Hbf    13:30
München Hbf     10:17   4:13    Wien Hbf    14:30
München Hbf     11:30   4:00    Wien Hbf    15:30
München Hbf     12:17   4:13    Wien Hbf    16:30
München Hbf     13:30   4:00    Wien Hbf    17:30
München Hbf     14:17   4:13    Wien Hbf    18:30
München Hbf     15:30   4:00    Wien Hbf    19:30
München Hbf     16:17   4:13    Wien Hbf    20:30
München Hbf     17:30   4:00    Wien Hbf    21:30
München Hbf     18:17   4:13    Wien Hbf    22:30
München Hbf     18:56   4:34    Wien Hbf    23:30
```

(It only shows three months or so into the future.)

Answer (score 5):

The European time table change takes place on December 9 – in Austria, some details of the 2019 timetable are still subject to change, but you can already check preliminary timetables for December 31 on http://fahrplan.oebb.at.

According to the timetable, on December 31 this year, direct high-speed trains will depart every two hours. Also taking into account (only slightly slower) train connections requiring a transfer in Salzburg, you have options to get from Munich to Vienna by train roughly every hour throughout the day.

In Vienna, public transport services will operate on a normal schedule, with additional (quite frequent) service during the night.